# Maintenance of Maha Meru 3D yantra at home

Tags: yantra

Over the past month, I have been doing both Maha Meru kumkumarchana and Shaligram abhisheka pooja. I simply started doing it one day and nobody advised me to do so. Now, I am at loss about how to maintain and clean Maha Meru as Kumkum (vermillion) gets accumulated in the inner edges of Maha Meru during kumkumarchana every day and does not come out upon cleaning with water. How do I maintain Maha Meru and clean it post kumkumarchana? Please advise me.